# partials error in Express NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, partials

I am trying to use partials in ExpressNodeJS.

My Node version is 3.x.

My project directory structure is as below.

```
D:\eclipse\workspace\test
```

I have created a sub-folder and added *headModule.ejs* in views as below

```
D:\eclipse\workspace\test\views\module\headModule.ejs
```

Below is my *index.ejs* file

> index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Include modules -->
<% include module/headModule.ejs %>

<title>Demo</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>

<body>

<!-- Include top part of login page -->
<% include module/top_login.ejs %>
```

When I run this code, below error is received.

> Express
>   500 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\partials\headModule.ejs'

Even if I change and adjust path in my *index.ejs* as

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Include modules -->
<% include ./views/module/headModule.ejs %>

<title>Demo</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>

<body>

<!-- Include top part of login page -->
<% include ./views/module/top_login.ejs %>
```

> Express 500 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'D:\eclipse\workspace\test\views\views\module\headModule.ejs'

In short, I tried setting the appropriate paths, but it goes either in *root directory as 1st error* or finds redundant *views folder as 2nd error*.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jay.
Let's imagine that you have the following structure for your views (test is a root directory) :

```
test
  views
    partials
    pages
```

So now if your page is sitting inside pages directory to call partials you need to eg: `<% include ../partials/header %>`, if you didnt configure your template engine to use different search options for your partials.

Hope this will help.

Comment: As described in OP; I have already tried this method and still getting the error. Thanks for response.